# Run text to speech automatically outside onInit

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

So right now when I run the app the function showLabel runs first than the Initializing of TTS. I always got an error that tts is null. Is there a better way of fixing this? Should I move my code on showLabel inside onInit? It has a parameter too. The goal would be the `firstObject` will be the text for the TTS. When i try to add .speak inside Oninit it works but when outside it would result in a null error. Any help would be thankful!

```
private var tts: TextToSpeech? = null
var firstObject = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_preview)

        tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)

fun showLabel(labels: List<FirebaseVisionImageLabel>?) {
        firstObject = labels!!.first().text
        Log.d(TAG, firstObject)
        tts!!.speak(firstObject, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")
    }

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // set US English as language for tts
            val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.US)

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS","The Language specified is not supported!")
            } else {
                Log.d("TTS", "Initilization Successful")
                tts!!.speak("This is a test", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "") // works
                cameraSource?.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(ImageLabelingProcessor())
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!")
        }

    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, by the way.  Looks like you're missing a close brace for onCreate?

Comment: @BooberBunz Sorry this is just a snippet of my code, but I can show the full code

Answer (score 0):

You can't call speak() on a TTS object that hasn't initialized yet.

Since you have speak() inside your showLabel() function, that means you can't call showLabel() before the TTS is initialized, either.

What you could do is create a class-level boolean variable, *ttsIsInitialized*, and set it to false until the TTS initializes... setting it true from inside onInit().

Then, in showLabel(), the first thing you do is check the boolean an if it's still false, then return/do nothing.